# QGIS - Create buffer circle around particular point using its geometry

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

Can I create a buffer circle around a particular point using its geometry in pyQGIS? I have my code as below:

```
myVariable = '123456'
expr = QgsExpression( "\"identificatie\"={}".format(str(myVariable)) )
it = point_layer2.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest( expr ) )
for i in it:
    # I can get the geometry here as i.geometry()
    point_layer2.select( i.id() )
    processing.runandload("qgis:fixeddistancebuffer", point_layer2, 250, 99, False, None)
    point_layer2.removeSelection()
```

I want to replace the select method and runandload method by something like this:

```
myVariable = '123456'
expr = QgsExpression( "\"identificatie\"={}".format(str(myVariable)) )
it = point_layer2.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest( expr ) )
for i in it:
    i.geometry().buffer(250,5)
```

But this has no output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
for i in it:
    i.geometry().buffer(250,5)
```

computes the buffer and then does nothing with it. To store that you need to create a new *polygon* layer and save the buffer polygon to it as a new feature.

Find a tutorial on adding new features to layers in QGIS Python and that should get you going.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.